# Enabling Users for LYNC 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, lync-2010, lync, ucma

Is there a way to enable users on the [Lync server](http://lync.microsoft.com/en-us/Overview/Pages/what-is-lync.aspx) via C#. I refer to the same functionality that runs when you go to Lync Server Control Panel, and creating a new Lync Server User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the [Enable-CSUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398711.aspx) powershell command from a C# app - see the articles [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2010/06/06/howtoenableusers.aspx) and [here](http://scorpiotek.com/blog/?p=770)

Comment: but, then the code has to run on the same machine as lync, this is not always possible. is there another way you know of?

Comment: The article I linked to describes how to run powershell commands remotely, meaning you should be able to run from any machine in the domain, provided you are running as a user with the correct privileges. Does this not work for you?

Comment: the lync shell calls this script on startup: